# Sending command to COM port

Tags: java, comm

I have a DateCS MP55 cashregister and i want it to print some lines, but i don't know what command i need to send to it and how . It's connected on COM5 and basically this is what i do send a '1' command. Is it the right way ?

```
 if (port_id.getPortType () == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                  {
                      System.out.println ("Serial port: " + port_id.getName ());
                  }
                  else if (port_id.getPortType () == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
                  {
                      System.out.println ("Parallel port: " + port_id.getName ());
                  } else
                      System.out.println ("Other port: " + port_id.getName ());

                  // Attempt to open it
                  try {
                      CommPort port = port_id.open ("PortListOpen",20);
                      System.out.println (port_id.getName()+" port opened successfully");
                      outputStream = port.getOutputStream();
                      String num = "1";
                      outputStream.write(num.getBytes());
                      port.close ();
                  }
```

This is what i found about "commands" for printing :

```
 P - print text:P,[logical number],______,_,__;[line 1];[line 2];[line 3];[line 4];[line 5];
If the line is empty, it is not printed out. If it contains only spaces, it will be printed as anempty line.
 MP-50 and MP-55 print out only the first line. The maximum number of symbolsper line is 24 for ECR and 30 for FP
```

So do i have to do something like this ? :

```
outputStream.write("P,[logical number],______,_,__;[line 1];[line 2];[line 3];[line 4];[line 5]".getBytes());
```

Comment: You need to follow what the command specification says. I've worked on Datecs LP-50, port communication should be the same. Java was too hectic for serial communication and opted for C# implementation. 

You can checkout my implementation on https://github.com/kosgeinsky/thermal-client-lp50/blob/master/thermal-printer-client/ThermalPrinterBridge.cs